# How to schedule one airflow DAG with 2 different scheduled interval with cron expression

Tags: python, cron, airflow

How to schedule one airflow DAG with 2 different scheduled interval with cron expression.

I want to combine below 2 intervals to schedule some airflow DAGs.
schedule interval = '30 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 * * *'  &     '00  3,6,12,15,18,21,00 * * *'

I am trying to run the DAG with 90 mins cadence and trying to skip 9 AM run.

please let me know if this is possible by any means ?

I tried to schedule with */90 0-8,10-23 * * *  but for some reason its not working  and seems it expects 00-59 as past parameter expression

Answer (score 1):

There is no possible to have a two cron expression in the single DAG out of the box into the Airflow. As well as it not possible to have some expressions in minutes not in the range 0-59, at least [`croniter`](https://pypi.org/project/croniter/), which is used in the Airflow, can't handle this case:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from croniter import croniter

it = croniter("*/90 * * * *", datetime(2023, 1, 1))
print(it.get_next(datetime))  # 2023-01-01 01:00:00
print(it.get_next(datetime))  # 2023-01-01 02:00:00
print(it.get_next(datetime))  # 2023-01-01 02:00:00
```

However you always have an option to use [Timetables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/timetable.html#timetables) which was introduced as part of [AIP-39: Richer scheduler_interval](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AIRFLOW/AIP-39+Richer+scheduler_interval) in Airflow 2.2.

Some useful links which might help you achive your requirements:

- [How-to Guides: Customizing DAG Scheduling with Timetables](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/timetable.html)
- [Astronomer: DAG scheduling and timetables in Airflow](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/scheduling-in-airflow#example-custom-timetable)

Comment: Thank you @Andrey Anshin. I have explored the Richer Scheduler Interval 
I tried the usercase 5 i.e.
tt = Timetable(
        _or(_and(Hours([3, 9, 18]), Minutes([2, 30, 19])),
            _and(
                    Hours([17]),
                    Minutes([0, 15, 45]),
        )))
However even after importing the required modules from airflow , I am getting Name error exception on boolean operators _or and _and , Do you have any working example for the above timetable format.

Comment: **AIP** (Airflow Improvement Proposals) it is an idea of new feature which make significant changes in Airflow codebase. It might contain pseudo-code which show the main idea, but there is not guarantee that final implementations would be exactly the same. If you interested which builtin Timetables available, you need to check the [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/timetable.html#built-in-timetables)

Comment: @JyotiprakashNayak you can check the example timetable code in this link https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/example_dags/plugins/workday.py